# Add a calculated field in Pivot Table

Tags: vba, excel, pivot-table

I have created a pivot table and I want to add a column in it , in which it will print the difference (in value) between two other columns of the Pivot Table. I will provide the part of my code related to building the pivot table. As it is clear, I have tried something in the last part of it, but it wont print nothing. It runs but it just does not print anything . It only prints the Pivot Table correctly, but not the new column.

```
Dim DSheet As Worksheet
Dim PCache As PivotCache
Dim PTable As PivotTable
Dim PRange As Range

Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Set DSheet = Worksheets("Budget_Report")

Set PRange = DSheet.Range(Cells(1, 27), Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell))

Set PCache = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=PRange)
Set PTable = PCache.CreatePivotTable(TableDestination:=DSheet.Cells(15, 1), TableName:="PivotTable1")

With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1")
 With .PivotFields("T-Lane")
    .Orientation = xlRowField
    .Position = 1
    .Subtotals(1) = True
    .Subtotals(1) = False
 End With

With .PivotFields("Monthly Cost FCST")
    .Orientation = xlDataField
    .Position = 1
    .Function = xlAverage
    .NumberFormat = "0.00"
    .Caption = "Monthly Cost Forecast"
End With

With .PivotFields("Monthly Vol FCST")
    .Orientation = xlDataField
    .Position = 2
    .Function = xlAverage
    .NumberFormat = "0.00"
    .Caption = "Monthly Vol Forecast"
End With

With .PivotFields("Monthly $/SU FCST")
    .Orientation = xlDataField
    .Position = 3
    .Function = xlAverage
    .NumberFormat = "0.00"
    .Caption = "Monthly $/SU Forecast"
End With

With .PivotFields("Monthly Cost Actuals")
    .Orientation = xlDataField
    .Position = 4
    .Function = xlSum
    .NumberFormat = "0.00"
    .Caption = "Monthly Cost Actual"
End With

With .PivotFields("Monthly Vol Actuals")
    .Orientation = xlDataField
    .Position = 5
    .Function = xlSum
    .NumberFormat = "0.00"
    .Caption = "Monthly Vol Actual"
End With

With .PivotFields("Monthly $/SU Actuals")
    .Orientation = xlDataField
    .Position = 6
    .Function = xlAverage
    .NumberFormat = "0.00"
    .Caption = "Monthly $/SU Actual"
End With

    .CalculatedFields.Add "Diff", "= 'Monthly Cost FCST'- 'Monthly Cost Actuals'"

End With
```

Comment: check https://stackoverflow.com/a/26970322/7889129

Comment: Did you try seeing what the macro recorder produced and then adapting?

Answer (score 2):

After adding the Calculated field, you need to set it's orientation to xlDataField to make it visible on the Pivot Table.

Try something like this...

```
.CalculatedFields.Add "Diff", "= 'Monthly Cost FCST'- 'Monthly Cost Actuals'"
.PivotFields("Diff").Orientation = xlDataField
```

Comment: Great it worked, but actually it does not print the results I want.. I tried to fix the formula of the column and the new formula that works is this one..  

          .CalculatedFields.Add "Diff", "=GETPIVOTDATA('Monthly $/SU Forecast',$A$15,'T-Lane','Athens to GREECE')-GETPIVOTDATA('Monthly $/SU Actual',$A$15,'T-Lane','Athens to GREECE')"
.PivotFields("Diff").Orientation = xlDataField

Comment: However, this new formula has an error as it says Unable to set property

Comment: Record macro while you create the calculated field manually and then analyze the code, that will give you an idea and then tweak it as per your requirement.